# Date math in elastic watcher email

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I would like to find the datetime for 1 day ago so that I can create link to kibana in an email sent from the watcher. Using Elasticsearch 5.0.2

I've tried the watch below but it returns an error of

```
ScriptException[runtime error]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Unable to find dynamic method [minusDays] with [1] arguments for class [org.joda.time.DateTime].];
```

minusDays does exist in the [joda DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) spec

but it doesn't exist in the [elastic codebase](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/joda/Joda.java)

here's the watch

```
PUT /_xpack/watcher/watch/errors-prod
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "daily": {
        "at": [
          "08:36"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "<das-logstash-{now}>",
          "<das-logstash-{now-1d}>"
        ],
        "types": [
          "redis-input"
        ],
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
              "query": {
                "match_all": {}
              }
          }
      }
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "send_email": {
            "transform": {
        "script" : "return [ 'from' : ctx.trigger.scheduled_time.minusDays(1) ]" 
      },
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "from": "noreply@email.com",
        "to": [
          "me@email.com"
        ],
        "subject": "errors",
        "body": {
          "html": "<html><body><p>from {{ctx.payload.from}}</p><p>to {{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}</p></body></html>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar and was able to hack this together by modifying a comment that almost worked from an elastic forum.

```
  "transform": {
      "script" : {
        "source" : "def payload = ctx.payload; DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'\"); ctx.payload.from = df.format(Date.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(ctx.execution_time.getMillis() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ))); return payload"
      }
  },
```

Hope that helps!